# nextbillion map api integration in angular project

Tags: angular, direction

I am trying to implement the nextbillion map service in my angular project so when i hitting the direction api I am getting this response:

```
   {
"status": "Ok",
"routes": [
    {
        "geometry": "ilseEbihiU?B?BGDa@VLXJZJVBF`@nADHBFDFBDJVBFDJ@HBHBHBJDP?^CZC`@CTEVI`@Sn@O^Sf@u@nBo@jAm@hAMVKPS`@mAbBU\\S^QX[l@Y`@m@z@}BbD_ArA{B`DGJq@bAKNKLOPg@l@OPSTe@d@c@`@g@`@c@^[Rk@b@_@Tc@VOHULMHOHc@Tc@RMDSJ]HODKBg@NQDa@JIB]HMBk@Li@Fu@LuCd@iBZsDl@c@Hc@Fs@J_AJ}@FgAHiAFy@Bu@BY@i@?oA?qAAoAEoAGoAKmAME?UE_C_@iJkAqASoHeA}GaAoCa@s@Gi@I]GOCOA]IgCe@_BSkDa@uEq@{AU}AU_@ESE_C]_@EKAsB[w@KiBWWEsCa@sC_@gBYsC_@m@KgDe@aAOkAQw@Ky@M}Cc@e@GcG{@qFy@[EqASwDc@uAMsAMkCQ{BKoBGy@AU?_ACaBA{@?kB?q@?sA?w@?w@?Q?a@?yA?cI?uF?Y?K?gF?yGAqB@e@?g@AaA@aAAgG?sEAeA?kB@iE?oA?_K@e@A}@@uCAuB@gBBaBFqBJ{AJK@[B]@iBRaBR_BT_BVgARwAX_ATm@NUDoAZkBd@iAXSFUFiFrAsDfA_D`AiBj@u@RqAb@m@PgLfDsA`@mJjCuErA{@Ti@P{@VGBw@VkA^{Ah@oC`ASJeFnBEBm@Pe@R{EbBcBn@cA`@}@^q@Xe@T[RKHMJOJOHwC`B]Tm@`@y@j@kAz@m@d@OJKJMLQNQNmAhA}@bAmArAcBxBoAhBMR[j@uA`CaC|E}@fBeArBeA~B[n@Yh@Ud@[j@W`@U^QV[b@UXGHEDGFy@l@GHMNURMJKHq@l@m@h@UNe@\\YPi@\\u@b@i@X_@PGB_EjByBdAcAd@_Av@OHKDKFMFqBfAa@Ty@h@aAv@s@l@iAfA}@fAw@`ASZSVMROXSXINk@jAQ\\KTe@hAw@xB[`Ag@~Ae@rAY|@IVK\\]bA[bASn@_@~@Wn@Wl@k@lAi@bAWd@e@t@[d@c@n@[d@}AnB_@^WZ]^[XuDdDw@r@QNSPOLmAdAm@j@a@\\yChCsAfAOLSROLg@b@C@q@l@]ZGDQNKHGDOL{CpCKFEFUJQLQHEBm@f@y@p@}BnBaA|@SPmAdAWTUR[V]\\?zBEfGK~AE|AJpC?|F?fGAdEFJAbH?hCG`HKEzBtA?d@?","distance": 333994.1,
        "duration": 11705.4,
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "value": 333994
                },
                "duration": {
                    "value": 11705
                },
                "steps": []
            }
        ]
    }
],
"country_code": "US"
```

how can I integrate this response to display this in angular html file :
format this question

The response I am getting from the api and I have recieved the geometry in response I want to use this geometry in my angular to display the direction on map